# Drop down list with pop up messages

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm using Excel 2013 on Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit.

I have a drop down list with many options to select.

- When I select option 5 from the drop down list I need warning message to pop up "you select option 5"
- When I select option 4 the cell color should change
- If I leave the drop down list without selecting any option a message should pop up asking me to "select one option from drop down"

How do I achieve this?

[EDITED]

I wrote the above code on my excel sheet, i went to Developer tab then i clicked on visual basic then i selected workbook

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
  If Target.Address = "Sheet2!$A$3" Then 
    MsgBox "Hello World!" 
  End If 
End Sub
```

"Sheet2!$A$3" when user select this option from drop down list message appear.

I enabled macro but still not working, any ideas??

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please change "Sheet2!$A$3" to "$A$3" - I suppose you have added the macro to the same worksheet? Try it please without "Sheet2" !

Answer (score 0):

You need basically to use macro Worksheet_Change like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "<address of drop-down>" Then
        ' something
    End If
End Sub
```

Try it and show where you stuck (if you stuck) :)